# Jenkins Update xcode app version to Hockeyapp

Tags: ios, xcode, hudson, jenkins, testflight

I'm developing a CI (Continuous Integration) for my application.

So, I'm using Jenkins with [HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net) (equal to [TestFlyApp](https://testflightapp.com)).

The problem is that HopckeyApp only accepts new versions of an application if it different versions from the last one added, else it gives me an error of already existing version, and no update.

I was reading about the apple tool **Agvtool** to update the value **CFBundleShortVersionString**.

My main problems are,

- how to do this in Jenkins automatically.
- How to update the project repository (Git in my case),for the next build it knowing which is the last version that was updated, or any other option to keep track of the last version updated.

I am trying to do this, but other approach will be accepted has well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is recommended to update the `CFBundleVersion` and not the `CFBundleShortVersionString`, see http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/how-tos/how-to-do-versioning-for-beta-versions-on-ios-or-mac

The following blog posts goes through the whole setup and also shows how to automatically update the version number using git tags: http://monitzer.com/?p=75

Here is another approach using git to update the version number: https://gist.github.com/3395649